# Solution of a boundary value problem with an implicitly-defined function

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

Assume I must solve the boundary value problem (BVP)

$$ -y''(x)+f(x)y(x)=g(x), $$

with $y(0)=0$ and $y(a)=0$.

The function $ g(x)$ is defined and known, but the function $ f(x)$ is defined implicitly by $$ f^{-1}(x)=h(x), $$ for a known function $ h(x)$.

My question is - if the function $f(x)$ is defined implicitly, how can we numerically approximate the BVP?

Comment: Probably, if the inverse of "h" is not well-defined on parts of the domain. Otherwise, the only problem will be the inversion of "h" which may result in numerical error.